# Journey Builder Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am having issues with the Journey Builder Activation.

Following data extension is configured in Contact Builder Data Designer, with Contact Key to Subscriber Key in one to one relationship.

The data extension contains the following fields.

SubscriberKey with type text and is set as primary key
Email Address with type Email Address
First Name with type text

When I select this DE as the entry source and put the condition for entry as Email Address is not null.

When I try to activate the journey it pops up with error 'An entry event must be configured before activation can be successful.'

Please note that this data extension is sendable with Subscriber Relates to Subscriber Key.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the Journey settings configured?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to put the Journey schedule in place.

[image]

Comment: I have also put the schedule in place. But still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. Somehow the entry criteria got invalid which was causing the issue. However, the error on the UI does not provide the right answer. Support helped to resolve this issue.
Thanks